# Counting nodes in BST implemented pseudoclasically mplementing countNodes without a inner subroutine through Javascript

Tags: javascript

I came up with one with a inner subroutine, but am having difficulty coming up with a solution without one, the this keyword makes things a bit more complicated for me.

```
BinarySearchTree.prototype.countNodes = function () {
  var count = 1;

  var recurseNodes = function(node) {
    if (node.left) {
      count++;
      recurseNodes(node.left);
    }
    if (node.right) {
      count++;
      recurseNodes(node.right);
    }
  }

  recurseNodes(this);

  return count;
}
```

this is the rest of the implementation

```
var BinarySearchTree = function(value){

  this.value = value;
  this.left = null;
  this.right = null;

};

BinarySearchTree.prototype.insert = function(nodeValue) {
  if (nodeValue < this.value) { 
    if (this.left) {
      this.left.insert(nodeValue);
    } else {
      this.left = new BinarySearchTree(nodeValue);
    }
  } else if (nodeValue > this.value) {
    if (this.right) {
      this.right.insert(nodeValue);
    } else {
      this.right = new BinarySearchTree(nodeValue);
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: It's a good task you're working on, but you need to develop a specific question. It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Also, I tested this code, the insert seems to be working fine. What do you need help on?

Comment: Implementing countNodes without a inner subroutine

Comment: This might be more suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just can call `countNodes` method recursively on the child nodes, given that they are instances of `BinarySearchTree` as well.

```
BinarySearchTree.prototype.countNodes = function () {
  var count = 1;
  if (node.left)
    count += node.left.countNodes();
  if (node.right)
    count += node.right.countNodes();
  return count;
}
```

You might make it even more elegant by using a static `BinarySearchTree.countNodes(node)` method that takes a node or `null`, but I'll leave that as an exercise to you.